# Angularjs multiple select box is un-selectable after scope data change in IE

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, multiple-select

I have multiple select box using angularjs. Its working fine in chrome. but in ie after change the scope it cant be select, it stuck the ui.

I have two multiple select box select a set from one and move to other by a click on move button. It work first move then after this will be freeze the select box.

```js
$scope.pickListArray = [{"name":"abc1"},{"name":"abc2"},{"name":"abc3"},{"name":"abc4"},{"name":"abc5"},{"name":"abc6"},{"name":"abc7"},{"name":"abc8"}];

$scope.changeView = function (val){
  $scope.pickListArray1 = val;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" ng-model="searchText">
<select class=" form-control" multiple ng-model="viewItem" ng-change="changeView(viewItem)" ng-options="pickName as pickName for pickName in pickListArray | filter:searchText"></select>
</div>


<div class="div2">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" ng-model="searchText1">
<select class=" form-control" multiple ng-model="viewItem1" ng-change="changeView1(viewItem1)" ng-options="pickName1 as pickName1 for pickName1 in pickListArray1 | filter:searchText"></select>
</div>
```

Please help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for it. I have used angular version 1.3.3. Multi select freeze is its version issue in ie. Just updated to 1.5.5. so fixed the same